# .net WebSocket: CloseOutputAsync vs CloseAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, websocket

We have a working ASP.NET Web API REST service that uses WebSockets on one of our controller's methods using HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketResponse(..).

The socket handler the code looks something like this...

```
public async Task SocketHandler(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
{
    _webSocket = context.WebSocket;
    ...
    while(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(inputSegment, cts.Token).Result;
        WebSocketState currentSocketState = _webSocket.State;

        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close ||
            currentSocketState == WebSocketState.CloseReceived)
        {
            // Should I use .CloseAysnc() or .CloseOutputAsync()?
            _webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "client requested", cts.Token).Wait();
        }

        if (currentSocketState == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

What is difference between .CloseAsync() and CloseOutputAysnc()?  I tried both and they both seemed to work fine, but there must be some difference.  They both have very similar descriptions on MSDN...

**System.Net.WebSockets.CloseAsync** -- Closes the WebSocket connection as an asynchronous operation using the close handshake defined in the WebSocket protocol specification section 7.

**System.Net.WebSockets.CloseOutputAsync** -- Initiates or completes the close handshake defined in the WebSocket protocol specification section 7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://www.salmanq.com/blog/5-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-net-websockets/

> ...The graceful way is CloseAsync which when initiated sends a message to the connected party, and waits for acknowledgement. ...The other option is to use CloseOutputAsync this is more of a “fire-and-forget” approach. ...

It looks like you're getting a closing message;

```
if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close ||
            currentSocketState == WebSocketState.CloseReceived)
```

so I'd say you'd be just fine using `CloseOutputAsync` because you've already gotten a message that says "I want to close this connection".

Comment: plus one. Though <sarcasm>I like how the authors of the referenced article and https://mcguirev10.com/2019/08/17/how-to-close-websocket-correctly.html have taken the time to update the official Microsoft docs rather than write their own blog posts</sarcasm>